# Getting "Connection is not recognized as a valid connection manager type" error in SSIS 2008 R2, but package runs fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

One of my primary SSIS import packages has been showing the following error the last few times it's been run. The data loads exactly how it should, just with this one error which doesn't seem to make a real difference. I would like to get it cleared up though.

Here is the error:

> Error      1              Error loading Update.dtsx: The connection type "OLEDB" specified for connection manager "SQL.Staging" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type. This error is returned when an attempt is made to create a connection manager for an unknown connection type. Check the spelling in the connection type name.                  D:\SSIS Projects\Update.dtsx           1              1
>
> Error      2              Error loading Update.dtsx: Error loading value "  0  SQL.Staging  {925404E7-27AA-4C4E-337B-D6058341" from node "DTS:ConnectionManager".        D:\SSIS Projects\Update.dtsx           1              1
>
> Error      3              Error loading 'Update.dtsx' : The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.  .                D:\SSIS Projects\Update.dtsx           1              1

As I said, the package runs fine. It doesn't seem to have any issues with the OLEDB source or destination's, which is what the error seems to indicate. Any other recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: The error indicates that the connection manager, `SQL.Staging` being used in the Execute SQL Task doesn't match a Connection Manager in the package. What's your package doing? What changed to make this break? It could be that someone renamed the CM and the component didn't get updated. Open the Task, select the correct CM and save/deploy and all should be right. It could be working because the Execute SQL Task never runs. It could be working because there is an explicit configuration fixing the problem during run-time. Without seeing more of your package, it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not able to check that solution out right now, but I will later today. One question: how do you know that the error relates to an Execute SQL Task?

Comment: `The connection type "OLEDB" specified for connection manager "SQL.Staging" is not recognized as a valid connection manager type.` And since I see Update.dtsx and Update_M25.dtsx in your error messages, I'm guessing you're doing some parent-child stuff which might also be the cause of the error.

Comment: Those are actually the same package, I just made a mistake when I shortened the file names. Think of that simply as Update.dtsx